# i have made one app to get ascii value of my character that i am going to put in my edit text but when i press my button to conver my app gets closed

Tags: java, android

i have made one app to get ascii value of my character that i am going to put in my edit text. i have made the code as-> `

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button=findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView textview=findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    EditText edittext=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
    String sipla=edittext.getText().toString();
    Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);

       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {

               int t=sipla.charAt(0);
               textview.setText("THE ASCII value of your character = "+t);

           }


       });`
```

but when i click my button my app gets closed. one more think
when i make certain changes in my code and put String sipla=edittext.getText().toString(); in my button setonclick function it works and everything is normal please tell me why my app was not working prevously .

Comment: this is my doubt please anyone help me out with this as i am new in android development. my doubt is basically why my app gets closed automatically when i put this string s= edittext.gettext(),tosstring() function outside the button.setonclicklistener() function but works when i put it inside button.setonclicklistener() . whats the reason

Comment: you have the ability to edit your question, dont add more information in comments

Comment: Just FYI-  this won't get you the ASCII value, because Java doesn't use ASCII strings.  It would get you the unicode UTF-16 value of the character (which will be equal to ASCII for standard latin characters, but also have a ton of other possible values).

Answer (score 0):

The reason your app is crashing is because `sipla` is empty, and you try to get the first character from an empty string. The reason it is empty is that you get it in `onCreate`, before the user has had a chance to enter anything in the EditText. Even if they enter something later, you never update the value of `sipla`.

The fix for this is simple - don't get the value from the EditText until you are actually ready to use it and the user would have had time to enter something - so get it *inside* `onClick`.

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    // This code runs as the activity is getting set up
    Button button=findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView textview=findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    EditText edittext=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
    Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);

    // if you get the value of edittext here it will always be empty,
    // at this point the user hasn't even seen the screen yet
 
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
            // This code runs much later, when the user 
            // clicks the button
 
            // Don't get the string until you are ready to process it, this code
            // doesn't run until the user clicks the button, at which
            // time edittext may also have a user value in it
            String sipla = edittext.getText().toString();
            
            if( !sipla.isEmpty() ) {
                int t=sipla.charAt(0);
                textview.setText("THE ASCII value of your character = "+t);
            }
            else {
                textview.setText("You didn't enter anything");
            }
       }
    });
}
```

Also, if your app crashes, look in the Logcat tab to see the full error message and stack trace. Learn to read that - it is an invaluable debugging skill. Also, learn to use Log/print statements in your code to help you understand what values are being used and what order things are run in when you are confused.